# HttpLoggingInterceptor or Logcat log's redacted, how to make it not redacted?

Tags: android, logging, retrofit2

Somehow the logs in Logcat of HTTP response (using HttpLoggingInterceptor) are redacted. Here's my retrofit configuration code using Hilt, then I use Retrofit as is normally.

```kotlin
@Provides
fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
    return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
}

@Provides
fun provideOkHttpClient(
    authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor,
    loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
        .build()
}
```

Then I got something like this :

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST ******************************************************************************************************************************
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 57
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"battery_level":100.0,"**************,"****************}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (57-byte body)
```

The redacted log :

1. The request URL which should be "https://example.com".
2. Some of the request JSON Body, there are latitude and longitude data which names are "lat" and "lng".

My retrofit & logging dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1"
}
```

State: Running in Debug mode.

```
 debug {
     applicationIdSuffix ".dbg"
     minifyEnabled false
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

     buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "\"https://example.com\"")
}
```

How to make it not redacted?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: That is the way that `HttpLoggingInterceptor` is designed. It redacts the logs where sensitive information may be logged. If you don't want that then don't use `HttpLoggingInterceptor`. Just write your own `Interceptor` that logs whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't find any clue, but somehow it back to normal when I uninstalled the apps and restart the Android Studio without any code / config changed.